# update and delete with codeigniter+ jeasyui

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

someone please help me !!
do not know what's wrong :(
update and delete in my project is not running -_-
This code is correct I guess. it's just really not running properly
thanks before :D

its my controller. its just my function update and delete

```
function update($id=null){
    if(!isset($_POST))  
        show_404();
    if($this->m_user->update($id))
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
    else
        echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'Failed Update'));
}    
function delete(){
    if(!isset($_POST))  
        show_404();

    $id = intval(addslashes($_POST['id']));
    if($this->m_user->hapus($id))
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
    else
        echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'Failed Delete'));
}
```

its function update and delete in my models

```
function update($id){
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    return $this->db->update('user',array(
                'name'=>$this->input->post('name',true),
                'address'=>$this->input->post('address',true),
                'dob' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $this->input->post('dob')))), 
                'email'=>$this->input->post('email',true),
                'username'=>$this->input->post('username',true),
                'password'=>$this->input->post('password',true),
                'level'=>$this->input->post('level',true)));
}

function delete($id){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    return $this->db->delete('user', array('id' => $id)); 
}
public function getJson()
{
    $page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
    $rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
    $sort = isset($_POST['sort']) ? strval($_POST['sort']) : 'id';
    $order = isset($_POST['order']) ? strval($_POST['order']) : 'asc';
    $offset = ($page-1) * $rows;

    $result = array();
    $result['total'] = $this->db->get('user')->num_rows();
    $row = array();

    $this->db->limit($rows,$offset);
    $this->db->order_by($sort,$order);
    $criteria = $this->db->get('user');

    foreach($criteria->result_array() as $data)
    {   
        $row[] = array(
                'name'=>$data['name'],
                'address'=>$data['address'],
                'dob'=>$data['dob'],
                'email'=>$data['email'],
                'username'=>$data['username'],
                'password'=>$data['password'],
                'level'=>$data['level'],
        );
    }
    $result=array_merge($result,array('rows'=>$row));
    return json_encode($result);
}
```

}

its javascript in my view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url;
    function newUser(){
        $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','New User');
        $('#fm').form('clear');
        url = '<?php echo site_url('admin/tambahuser'); ?>';
    }
    function editUser(){
        var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
        if (row){
            $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Edit User');
            $('#fm').form('load', row);
            url = '<?php echo site_url('admin/ubah'); ?>/'+row.id;
        }
    }
    function saveUser(){
        $('#fm').form('submit',{
            url: url,
            onSubmit: function(){
                return $(this).form('validate');
            },
            success: function(result){
                var result = eval('('+result+')');
                if (result.errorMsg){
                    $.messager.show({
                        title: 'Error',
                        msg: result.errorMsg
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#dlg').dialog('close');        // close the dialog
                    $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function destroyUser(){
        var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
        if (row){
            $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to Delete this user?',function(r){
                if (r){
                    $.post('<?php echo site_url('admin/hapus'); ?>',{id:row.id},function(result){
                        if (result.success){
                            $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                        } else {
                            $.messager.show({    // show error message
                                title: 'Error',
                                msg: result.errorMsg
                            });
                        }
                    },'json');
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please check the **url** in javascript by using `console.log(url)` because you have write `<?php echo site_url('admin/tambahuser'); ?>` instead of that write `<?php echo site_url("admin/tambahuser"); ?>`

Comment: oke thanks for your answer :D
but now the eror is move to
  var result = eval('('+result+')'); at view
can you help me again? :')

Answer (score 0):

The **var url** in the "text/javascript" is looking for an existing php extension file located on the same folder or subfolder of this page. So what you should place after the "url = ..." should be an existing php file on the same folder.